# how to keep a program connected to a document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

maybe this is a unique question.. yet I have a scanner for links on my documents... indeed i have this schema called `botsSchema`

```
const botsSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
   },
   running: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
   }
})
```

So for my system, each user has a bot that is running for them to scan our products. When a bot is connected, it turns the value of running to `true` by using `findOneAndUpdate()` and when it turns the value back to `false` pre-closing.

Sometimes bots can disconnect with error without even able to pre-change the value of `running` to `false` so it'd still seem like the bot is running, while it is not.
I want to have a constraint that if `running` value is not updated for (let's say) 5 minutes it would return back to `false` value by default, how can I achieve this with `mongoose`?